# how to install react native without node?

Tags: php, reactjs, react-native, v8, php-7

here it is what i did and how i came on this question .

i am trying my hands on react.js ( with server side rendering) , in my development environment i use php with web server Apache 2 and nginx on ubuntu 14.04

so i follow this step to install apache2 and PHP7 :

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get install -y php7.0
sudo apt-get install php7.0-cli php7.0-common libapache2-mod-php7.0 php7.0 php7.0-mysql php7.0-fpm php7.0-curl php7.0-gd php7.0-mysql php7.0-bz2
sudo apt-cache search php7-* 
sudo apt-get install php-all-dev php7.0-dev
```

so my apache2 is default on port 80 and i install nginx on port 8080

```
sudo apt-get install nginx
```

i configure /etc/nginx/sites-enabled and made nginx listen on port 8080

so my web servers are up and running , now i need to install v8 engine with my php for server side rendering .

i did it like this : [new version of V8 engine (4.9) on GNU/Linux](https://github.com/phpv8/v8js/blob/master/README.Linux.md)

and it's working fine , now i am able to do serverside rendering with the help of v8 engine

i want to learn react-native so i found this link

[react-native app ( We’ll be using PHP as the server-side language )](https://www.sitepoint.com/build-android-app-react-native/)

as part of setup

- Install Android Studio
- Installation of react native

to install react native there is official link [react-native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html)

**which say's i need to install node js for that but one thing i don't understand is node use v8 engine but i have already v8 engine installed so why can't i use it with react-native ??**

can some one please  guide me on this .

!!!  Thanks for your time and support  !!!

Comment: Node is more than just v8.  React needs that "more".

Comment: dose it means i mush have node to work with react-native . i can not run it with PHP ?

Comment: @SLaks is there any way that i can run react-native with PHP ?

Comment: React-native runs on the client device.  PHP runs on the server.  What would that even mean?

Comment: @SLaks

i mean to say like how node uses v8 on back side and it runs with react-native .

like that only i have php with v8 on my server side then is there any way to work with react-native with out node ?? 

sorry for the grammar english is not my native language..

Comment: React-native uses Node.js for the development tooling.  No part of it has anything to do with any server.

Comment: Thank you so much for instant reply   !!!